# Derivative Problem asked in interview.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{x^2-\sqrt{x}+2}{x}\right)
$$
I was giving the exam of a company and they have asked me to solve this question.
I used L'Hospital rule to solve this question but got stuck
as first derivative becomes.
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\left(2x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)
$$
And then I said function is not defined at a given limit.
But interviewer said it is defined at given limit and answer is 2.
Solution provided by the company[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6enW6.png)

Comment: Read the necessary conditions to apply L'Hospital.

Comment: For $x\to 0$, the original limit is not in $\frac 00$ form.

Comment: Also the limit isn't 2...

What company is giving interviewee's freshman calculus questions (and also getting them wrong)?

Comment: Throw L’Hôpital in the garbage bin.

Comment: The limit does not exist. The solution is 100% wrong.

Comment: @TedShifrin plus that company also.

Comment: Limit evaluates directly to $ 2/0$ , no need to apply  L’Hôpital ... n do not regret if you did n't get in there.

Comment: Be glad you whiffed.  You don't want to work at that company.  They are dead wrong.  "What company is giving interviewee's freshman calculus questions (and also getting them wrong)? " Sadly I bet it's not that uncommon.

Comment: Wow! they are not only wrong about using L'hopital (you *can't* use l'hopital) but the are wrong about $\frac {1\times 2\sqrt x}{2\sqrt x} \ne \sqrt x$.  It equals $\frac 1{\sqrt x}$.  They are.... well, it really irks me when idiots tell other people they are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company is wrong. L'Hopital's rule does **not** apply because $\frac{2}{0}$ is not an indeterminate form.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{x^2+\sqrt{x}+2}{x}=\frac{0^2+\sqrt{0}+2}{0}=\frac{2}{0}=\text{DNE}$$

Comment: Plugging in $x=0$ doesn't show the limit fails to exist, at least not without some additional explanation. However, by keeping only the dominate terms we have $\frac{2}{x},$ so we get $-\infty$ for $x \rightarrow 0^-$ and $+\infty$ for $x \rightarrow 0^+$ (i.e. each one-sided limit exists infinitely), and therefore the (two-sided) the limit doesn't exist finitely or infinitely.